# View in one schema and table in another schema

Tags: sql-server, view, database-schema, access-rights

I have a Table created by db_owner

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TableTest](
[ID] [int] NULL,
[Cost] [int] NULL,
[partnumber] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Another table with the same definition, but in an another custom schema.

```
CREATE TABLE [Test].[TableTest](
[source] [int] NULL,
[cost] [int] NULL,
[partnumber] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

If I create a view like so:

create view [Test].[ViewTest] as select * from dbo.TableTest

When I do a select on the newly created view I obtain the results from the Test.TableTest, not from dbo.TableTest as expected.
What is happening?

Answer (score 0):

This may happens if after you created the `Test.MyView` you change the structure of the base tables (example: you add / remove columns / drop & recreate with other columns `[dbo].[TableTest]`). You have to use `sp_refreshview`.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TableTest](
[ID] [int] NULL,
[Cost] [int] NULL,
[partnumber] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE SCHEMA Test
GO

CREATE TABLE [Test].[TableTest](
[source] [int] NULL,
[cost] [int] NULL,
[partnumber] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE VIEW [Test].[ViewTest] as select * from dbo.TableTest
GO

SELECT * FROM [Test].[ViewTest] 
/*
ID          Cost        partnumber
----------- ----------- -----------

(0 row(s) affected)
*/
GO

DROP TABLE [dbo].[TableTest];
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TableTest](
[source] [int] NULL,
[cost] [int] NULL,
[partnumber] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

-- From this moment Test.ViewTest should include source, cost and partnumber columns
-- but if we execute     SELECT * FROM [Test].[ViewTest]  SQL Server will show the same "old" columns

```
SELECT * FROM [Test].[ViewTest] 
/*
ID          Cost        partnumber
----------- ----------- -----------

(0 row(s) affected)
*/
GO
```

-- The solution: sp_refreshview

```
EXEC sp_refreshview 'Test.ViewTest'
GO
SELECT * FROM [Test].[ViewTest] 
/*
source      cost        partnumber
----------- ----------- -----------

(0 row(s) affected)
*/
GO
```